# How can I do multiple h1 elements replace to h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h1>
                    <a href="#">@item.Title</a>
                </h1>
            </div>
        }
```

Result; (Post per page: 6)

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h1>
        <a href="#">@item.Title</a>
    </h1>
</div>
```

...

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h1>
        <a href="#">@item.Title</a>
    </h1>
</div>
```

six h1 elements

How can I replace all h1 elements to h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 in javascript ?

Like this:

```
    <div class="panel-heading">
    <h1>
        <a href="#">@item.Title</a>
    </h1>
</div>

<div class="panel-heading">
    <h2>
        <a href="#">@item.Title</a>
    </h2>
</div>
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3>
        <a href="#">@item.Title</a>
    </h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h4>
        <a href="#">@item.Title</a>
    </h4>
</div>

<div class="panel-heading">
    <h5>
        <a href="#">@item.Title</a>
    </h5>
</div>

<div class="panel-heading">
    <h6>
        <a href="#">@item.Title</a>
    </h6>
</div>
```

Comment: Can u not have a counter inside the loop and dynamically add the heading level? like <h@counter>...</h@counter> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this (it isn't pretty, but it works). Also here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rk5bj77x/).

```
var count = 1;
$(".panel-heading > h1").each(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith($("<h" + count + ">" + this.innerHTML + "</h" + count + ">"));
  count++;
})
```

Comment: @Zalu sure thing, glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a jQuery selector to get all those h1 tags, and loop through them and generate the h1 to h6 tags and use replaceWith to replace the h1 to the new tags.

The below code will do h1 to h6. If there are more than 6 h1 tags, It will put those in a p tag after the h6.

```
$(function(){

  $(".panel-heading").find("h1").each(function(a,b){
      var newTag='<p'+(a+1)+' \>';
      if(a<=5)
      {
         newTag='<h'+(a+1)+' \>';
      }        
      var content=$(b).html();      
      var s=$(newTag).append(content);
      $(b).replaceWith(s)
  });

});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/gehexaqaqu/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working js bin

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this server-side:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Length; i++)
{
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h@(i)>
            <a href="#">@Model[i].Title</a>
        </h@(i)>
    </div>
}
```